# Nikon D7000 - image playback always has info bar?

Tags: nikon-d7000

When I first got my D7000 I'm sure that the image playback showed pictures in pure form without information as the default. Now, i always have a rather annoying info bar at the bottom plus the image number in the top right. The display options menu offers no way to remove this so I'm completely stumped. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

The playback modes for your camera are summarized on page 165 of [the manual](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D7000_ENnoprint.pdf):

[image: D7000 image playback modes, from p. 165, User Manual]

After taking a picture, the automatic image playback will always show some sort of information, depending on the last Photo Information mode used/selected.

If you want to see the image without *any* information overlay, press the Zoom In button, and it will show the image only. But that will never be the default view.

Comment: Thank you. It's a bit distracting to be forced to view extraneous information - especially the image number sequence! - but if that's the way it is, there is nothing that can be done.

Comment: Hmm… only having a D5500 I was about to say just press the up button until you find the version with image only… but they really did leave it out on the D7000. Mine has a 7th option, 'none'.